# Why is 1 << 4 being used instead of 16 for constant DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY in HashMap.java?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class HashMap<K,V>
extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
{
    /**
     * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
     */
    static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4;//why not 16 here
```

Can somebody give better explanation?

Comment: I think that comment hints at the reason - by using left bit shift it makes it harder to accidentally use a number that is not a power of 2.

Comment: agree with davejagoda. Found the related article in quora: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-applications-of-bitwise-operators-right-shift-and-left-shift

Answer (score 3):

It is simple: a constant generated with a left shift of 1, eg 1 << N will always be a power of two.

It can be written other way, but this way would be more self-descriptive.
I think its completely equivalent, but it is written way to make clear how the value came and how its computed

like in this case (`1 << 4`) in this case that it was intended to be 2^4 ie 16.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @EJP thanks.. _text that isn't quoted_ can common ppl like us not quote anything.. :-)  joking..  was intending a highlight .. will take care nxt time..